# Are my hubs holes normal?

Tags: mountain-bike, hub

[image]

Are this holes normal? They are not slotted.

Comment: What do you mean with windowed? I’m not a native English speaker, am I missing a meaning of “window” related to wheel building here? To me the holes look perfectly fine, though it’s strange that they seem to have imprints/notches from spokes from a previous build but in all kinds of directions.

Comment: @Michael I guess "windowed" means oval ?

Comment: I think English speakers would say *slotted*, i.e. slots filed for large bladed spokes. Oval spokes like the Sapim CX-Ray will fit through standard spoke holes. We're talking about big blades here. I agree with the first answer that the marks are just from regular use. These days, because of relatively small bladed spokes, slotting hubs is rare.

Comment: OP, if you don’t mind, I’ve edited your question accordingly. You can revert the edit if you feel like this wasn’t accurate.

Answer (score 9):

This hub is obviously used. The dents at the edge of every second hole are wear caused by spokes that were mounted in a way they leave the hub at the outside. The spoke hole inbetween that are less dented had the spoke leave the hub on the back side, and the the less sharp heads of the spoke don't cause this much wear.

If you want to build a new wheel with that hub, I recommend you to either use exactly the same spoke scheme as in the wheel the hub came from (so the new spokes perfectly align with the wear marks) or mounting the outside spokes in holes that previously were used for the inside spokes and the other way around, the the weak marks don't affect the new spokes.